# Firefly Cartesian Conversion

Tags: c++, algorithm, 2d, cartesian-coordinates

I'm trying to use the algorithm of firefly, is based of the next source:

https://github.com/firefly-cpp/Firefly-algorithm--FFA-

I have the problem that it's  is giving me the highest point of a firefly and  I need to modify the code, to make the firefly give  me back  a point on a Cartesian plane. Could you give me a advice of how to start doing this